# Form validation in Django 2.2! Can't display any validation errors

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working with this simple form and can't able to display inline validation in each line. I want validation as it worked in the Django admin site, with particular fields. How could it be done! **It only shows the HTML validation like "Please fill out the field"**

**models.py**

```
class MemberRegistration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from . models import MemberRegistration
from django.core import validators

class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Name'}),
        max_length=100, error_messages = {
                 'required':"Please Enter your Name"})
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'E-mail'}),
        required=True, max_length=100)
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Phone'}),
        required=True, max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = MemberRegistration
        fields = "__all__"

    def clean_name(self):
        all_clean_data = super().clean()
        name = all_clean_data['name']
        if name == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Name field is required")
```

**member_form.html:**

```
    {% block body_block %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>This is member reg form</h1>
    <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Name</label>
         {{ form.name.errors }}
        {{form.name}}

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Email</label>
        {{ form.email.errors }}
        {{form.email}}

      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Phone</label>
        {{form.phone}}
        </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

How I can do this with Django's built-in validation?

Comment: What about reading the doc and following it ? [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages) for the validation errors,  and  [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) for correct field validation.

Comment: I was reading this for a long time from 2 days but can't actually get the exact point. @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Can't you see the differences between your code and the one in the doc ???

Comment: I can't find the exact solution. That's why I post it!

Comment: I see you've edited your question, fixing the first obvious issue in the template. You still have to add the form's "non field errors" to the template, fix your forms's `clean_name()` method (it must return the cleaned value), AND to add your view's code to your question (if you don't get the errors with a correct template, chances are the issue is because you don't pass the bound form back to template in the case of a validation error).